# Is there any direct/indirect relationship with the number of search results in choosing a successful keyword phrase?

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords, ranking, research

Is there any direct/indirect relationship with the number of search results in choosing a successful keyword phrase?

I have about 22,500,000 results for my keyword phrase, which I intend to target.

I think doing seo according to standards set by google, I will won half the battle. Now, if I give 1 year with other marketing techniques like adwords. **How much time will it take me to be on the first page for my targeted keyword phrase?**

Answer (score 2):

The lower the number of results, the lower the competition, the easier to out-rank.

Trying to beat 22.5million other web-pages for your search terms is kinda silly (in my humble opinion) unless you have an existing high-ranking site, with tons of authority and back-linking power.

It's worth understanding "the long tail" rather that chasing "glory terms":

- http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/08/03/09/long-tail-guide
- http://www.conversationmarketing.com/2010/10/long-tail-seo-101-defined.htm

Comment: @mike what according to you, is good number of other pages competing, so to dive in that search term? and thanks for your valuable suggestion :)

Comment: @jeet - there's no range of numbers. In terms of deciding a keyword strategy, i'd use something similar to what's outlined here: http://www.blueglass.com/blog/keyword-research-tips-strategies/